# How to work with Python custom packages in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pip, python-module

I have my app.py function that's using pip libraries like SQLAlchemy, etc... I am deploying this to AWS Lambda, so I am packaging app.py and all other dependencies into a zip.

1. Is there a better way to deal this? (What if pip libraries go out of date)
2. I have a custom code that I want to use in many programs. How do I create my own module and package it along with pip libraries?

Comment: This should help: https://towardsdatascience.com/python-packages-in-aws-lambda-made-easy-8fbc78520e30

Answer (score 3):

Yeap, I'll give you some alternatives to each of your questions:

1. Kind of, you could use a *framework ([chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice/)/[serverless](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-python-requirements)) to automatically handle packaging for you. Each deploy would fetch the most recent version (according to your `requirements.txt`) and package then for you. I recommend you to stick with a framework.
2. A Lambda [Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) is exactly what you need - Multiple lambdas will be able to run your module without overhead (in simple terms). There are a lot o references explaining how to create a layer and also about python packaging (You're the one who must evaluate the need to upload it to pypi)

In both cases, `serverless` is going to help you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1 - AWS SAM will work out your `requirements.txt` and bundle what's needed with your code. This works fine for small projects, but for larger ones I'd suggest going the same way as for library code - put all your deps in separate layer. It may be installed with `pip install -U --target dirname` and then packaged into a layer.